# Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

see the below trigger which return "Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" in oracle" error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TGR_DST AFTER INSERT ON  ADMISSION FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
P_hNO CHAR(10);
P_iNO CHAR(10);
P_ID INTEGER;
BEGIN
 SELECT hNO,iNO INTO P_hNO,P_iNO FROM ADMISSION WHERE iNO IN (SELECT MAX(iNO) FROM ADMISSION );
 SELECT MAX(ID)+1 INTO P_ID FROM Discharge;
 INSERT INTO Discharge(ID,hNO,iNO,in_TIME) VALUES(P_ID,P_hNO,P_iNO,SYSDATE);
END
```

Comment: Put a ; after the END and then a / below.

Comment: That will solve the compilation error, but you're querying the table the trigger is against, so you'll get a mutating table error at run-time. Why are you doing anything based on the max `ino` rather than the one you just inserted (`:new.ino`)? And why are you using `max+1` instead of a sequence for the discharge ID? (Never mind why you're recording someone as discharged automatically when they are admitted...)